# Is there any way to exclude the Modules from CTS in android

Tags: android, android-testing, cts

I am new to CTS , I tried to find out how to exclude certain modules from cts 9.0 while running the cts ,I didn't get it.
Is there any way to exclude the Modules from CTS in android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can exclude the modules using the below command.

```
run cts --exclude-module <ModuleName>
```